# How to force 'asp:Image' to load new 'imageUrl' ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, imageurl

I have a page that represents a "box" for example. In this box I have multiple images. I am showing each image information on a row inside a data grid view. What I am trying to achieve is showing the image itself under the grid by clicking on any row. What I have tried to do is the next:

In the code behind, while loading the grid, I am adding an attribute in the `ItemDataBound` event such as:

```
Private Sub dgrBox_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgrBox.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.DataItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim oBox As Box
        oBox = CType(e.Item.DataItem, Box)

        If oBox IsNot Nothing Then
                e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GetImage('" + oBox.ID.ToString() + "','" + oBox.Name + "');")                
        End If           
    End If
End Sub
```

In the `aspx` page I have the following:

```
<div id="divInfo" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 330px;">
    <table width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="divZoomSlider" style="overflow: auto;">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgRectoImg" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="300px" oncontextmenu="ZoomOutImage(this);return false;"
                                    onclick="ZoomInImage(this);"/>
                                <asp:Image ID="imgVersoImg" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="300px" oncontextmenu="ZoomOutImage(this);return false;"
                                    onclick="ZoomInImage(this);"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                            <input type="image" onclick="return FlipImage();" src="../Images/recto-verso-impression-icone-8241-32.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Plus in the header I have this `javascript` code that I am calling `onclick` from each row:

```
function GetImage(sID, sName) {
    try {
        var oimgRectoImg = document.getElementById("imgRectoImg");
        var oimgVersoImg = document.getElementById("imgVersoImg");
        oimgRectoImg.imageURL = "~/ImageDisplay.aspx?ID=" + sID + "&Mode=FULLSIZE&IMAGEDISPLAY=RECTO&TYPE=Out";
       // alert(oimgRectoImg.imageURL);
        oimgVersoImg.imageURL = "~/ImageDisplay.aspx?ID=" + sID + "&Mode=FULLSIZE&IMAGEDISPLAY=VERSO&TYPE=Out";
        //alert(oimgVersoImg.imageURL);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("GetImage: " + e.message);
    }
}
```

I already made sure with these alerts that my click event is fired. I also visited the `url` shown in the alert to make sure that everything is fine.

My problem is that when I click on any given row from the data grid, no image is displayed. I feel like I am missing something like refreshing the page or somehow refreshing the `asp:Image` to load the image from the new `imageUrl` that was assigned using the `javascript` code. I am not sure how to fix it since I have little experience with front-end development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageURL` is a server-side property only.

ASP.NET tags are just changed into HTML by the ASP.NET engine and then sent to the browser, which can only read HTML.

In the rendered HTML the attribute containing the URL is called "src". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Therefore changing `imageURL` to `src` as follows

```
 var oimgRectoImg = document.getElementById("imgRectoImg");
 var oimgVersoImg = document.getElementById("imgVersoImg");
 oimgRectoImg.src = "/ImageDisplay.aspx?ID=" + sID + "&Mode=FULLSIZE&IMAGEDISPLAY=RECTO&TYPE=Out";
 oimgVersoImg.src = "/ImageDisplay.aspx?ID=" + sID + "&Mode=FULLSIZE&IMAGEDISPLAY=VERSO&TYPE=Out";
```

should solve your problem, I think.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: ADyson, that works. There's only one thing that I had to change. I deleted the `~` from the start of the `src`. It didn't work with it.

Comment: No problem, good point about the `~` - again that gets resolved by ASP.NET when you write server-side code and turned into a full URL. You won't need it client-side because the browser will resolve a relative URL into a full one anyway. I have edited the question to remove it.

Comment: That explains it all. I should be more careful to distinguish between what is going to be resolved by the server and what would be resolved by the client.